# Склонение матерного слова на букву П

Tags: падежи, обсценная-лексика

Получить п*ов? Это кого/чего.
А как будет в остальных падежах? Хотя бы в именительном.

Comment: Нужны примеры слова пиздов, если такие есть, в других падежах.

Comment: Посмотрите склонение слова [**стол**](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/стол) во множественном числе. Ударение и окончания в слове из вопроса будут такими же.

Comment: Посмотрел, понял о чем вы, думал об этом, почему тогда тут https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0 нет слова пиздов?

Comment: Потому что это другое слово, всем известное, в женском роде. А "ваше", видимо, еще не закрепилось :))  в словарях, зато есть абсолютно синонимичное: [пиздюль](https://ru.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/пиздюль).

Comment: Тогда я ничего не понимаю. Можно без шарадно-ребусных загадок написать ответ?

Comment: Взяв за основу **звезду**, можно склонять по образу и подобию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно, в грамотном русском языке, пусть и матерном, слова ***"пиздов"*** нет. Это какое-то "олбанско-падонкаффское" коверканье слова ***"пиздюлей"***. Соответственно, и нормальной системы падежей у этого слова не может быть по определению.

Можно **"дать (*или* навешать) пиздюлей"** или **"дать пизды"**, эти формулировки практически синонимичны. И каждая хорошо согласуется в любых падежах.